# Can I take money from my employee stock and put it towards another stock?

Tags: investing, employee-stock-options, stocks

Can I take money from my employee stock and put it towards another stock?

Answer (score 4):

The question is for your HR department, or administrator of the plan. How long must you hold the employee shares before you are permitted to sell? Loyalty to your company is one thing, but after a time, you will be too heavily invested in one company, and you need to diversify out. One can cite any number they wish, 5%, 10%. All I know is that when Enron blew up, it only added insult to injury that not only did these people lose their job, they lost a huge chunk of their savings as well.

Answer (score 2):

Only if you sell the stock in question, and use the proceeds to buy other stock.

(You should probably never feel bad about selling your company stock, even if it goes up a lot later, because from a risk-exposure basis you are already exposed to your company's performance through your *career*. Unless you have a *lot* of other savings, you should diversify.)